Kendo Column Menu -Custom filter for Date column
I've been using a kendo grid ,where we have made some enhancements for grid.We have set columnMenu to true in which Filter option will be shown as one of the menu. So when I click filter a multi select list will be shown with list of dates available in the grid. But the issue is ,this date was shown in GMT format .I want to modify it as MM/DD/YYYY format. I'm not sure where to include the format.
Here is my code snippet
 columnMenu: true,
                            filterable: {
                                mode: "menu,row"
                            },
 columns:
                                [{
                                    selectable: true, width: "37px",
                                },
                                {

                                    field: "Date",
                                    title: "Document Date",
                                    width: "200px",

                                    template: "#=(Date == null) ? ' ' : kendo.toString(Date, FormatDate().DateFormat + ' h:mm tt') #",
                                    filterable: {
                                        multi: true, search: true, format: "{0:"+FormatDate().DateFormat+"}",
                                        cell: {
                                            template: function (args) {
                                                args.element.kendoDatePicker({
                                                    format: FormatDate().DateFormat,
                                                    parseFormats: FormatDate().DateFormat,

                                                });
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    attributes: {
                                        style: "overflow-wrap: break-word;"
                                    },
                                    sortable: {
                                        compare: function (a, b, desc) {
                                            if (a.Date < b.Date) {
                                                return -1;
                                            }
                                            else if (a.Date > b.Date) {
                                                return 1;
                                            }
                                            return 0;
                                        }
                                    }

                                },

I'm expecting the list to show with different format like this
Expected functionality
But the issue is it is shown like this
Issue image

This question is similar to: Kendo grid date column not formatting. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You need to set the format configuration for the column:
{
  field: "Date",
  title: "Document Date",
  width: "200px",
  format: "{0: MM/dd/yyyy}",
  template: "#=(Date == null) ? ' ' : kendo.toString(Date, FormatDate().DateFormat + ' h:mm tt') #",
  ...
}

The template specifies how the table cells are rendered, but the provided format will be used when generating the multi checkbox options for the filter menu.
